# Sending mail with Outlook.Application C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I'm trying to send mail from my c#.net application, I've used this code:

```
var mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailItem.Subject = "Error Report from user: " + AuthenticationManager.LoggedInUserName;
    mailItem.HTMLBody = "Test email\n"+ReadSignature();
    mailItem.To = "test@test.com";
    mailItem.Display(true);
```

The mail doesn't get sent, but added to the outbox folder. I suspect that the mail isn't sent because outlook isn't started. So I googled and came up with this:

```
        var oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        var f = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        Thread.Sleep(5000); // a bit of startup grace time.

        var mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "Error Report from user: " + AuthenticationManager.LoggedInUserName;
        mailItem.HTMLBody = "Test email\n"+ReadSignature();
        mailItem.To = "test@test.com";

        mailItem.Display(true);
```

But once again it end up in the outbox folder. I need to start outlook, because I can't specify the FromMail property in every single client application.config. Any ideas?

Comment: if you are using web application then you can configure from mail in web.config file

Comment: Do you really need this overkill to simply send simple email? there are classes that allow sending mail directly without outlook.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [`MailItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779.aspx) method:

```
mailItem.Send();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the mail still gets inn my outbox folder in outlook.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen May be allowed inbox size is reached. if then email will go to outbox until enough space is available, did you check that ?

Comment: @AccessDenied No. But I fixed it by starting the outlook process and then open the create mail dialog.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen great!

Comment: Try to use Namespace.SyncObjects collection or Namespace.SendAndReceive method to start a sync. Note that message submission is an asynchronous process, so you will need to keep a reference to the Namespace object and the SyncObject (if you are using it) until the message is actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Namespace.SyncObjects collection or Namespace.SendAndReceive method to start a sync.

Note that message submission is an asynchronous process, so you will need to keep a reference to the Namespace object and the SyncObject (if you are using it) until the message is actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21434722/2090467) for similar question - it contains solution where you don't have to use

```
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```