# Outlook mailing application c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I use a very simple code to generate emails using outlook in my c# application. It works fine when Outlook is already opened.(Even though it asks for permission to open the email.But after I grant access a new Outlook message window opens with the generated email). But the real problem is if Outlook is not opened the application crashes at the line

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oTORecipt = oMsg.Recipients.Add(email);
```

> ERROR:An exception (first chance) of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Birthday_Mailing.dll.
>
> Additional information: discontinued operation (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
>
> If a handler is available for this exception, the program may continue to run safely.

And my whole code can be seen as below

```
public void SendMail(string email, string name)
    {
        //// Create the Outlook application by using inline initialization.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        ////Create the new message by using the simplest approach.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oTORecipt = oMsg.Recipients.Add(email); //oRecips.Add(t);
        oTORecipt.Type = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
        oTORecipt.Resolve();

        oMsg.Subject = "Herzlichen Glückwunsch";
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<title>Happy Birthday</title>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body style='background-color:#E6E6E6;'>" +SelectImage+
                "<div style='font-family: Georgia, Arial; font-size:14px; '>Liebe/r " + " " +
                name + ",<br /><br />" +
                "alles Gute zum <b>Geburtstag!</b>  Wir wünschen einen schönen Tag  und für das kommende Jahr Gesundheit, Glück und Erfolg." +
                 "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />" +
                "Mit den besten Grüßen,<br />" +
                "XXYYZZ" +
                "</div>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
            oMsg.Save();
            oMsg.Display();

            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
```

I'm not an expert in coding. Can someone help me to find where the actual problem is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't Recipients some kind of a list or array? Shouldn't you have some indexes or keys?

Comment: @Gnqz I had indexes but it was giving the same error back then too. And it works perfectly fine when the app is opened. So I don't think it is the actual problem. Something is wrong with the permission I guess

Comment: What type of database is your server using? Did you see this article? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b3ba89ca-48f9-47dd-92e2-c77d8585ac94/operation-aborted-exception-from-hresult-0x80004004-eabort

Comment: @Gnqz SQL server 2008. Im going to have a look on that article

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330101/can-only-send-email-via-outlook-if-outlook-is-open  - looks similar

Comment: @MikeMiller It works kinda fine. But has to test more before post it as an answer. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;
```

I added this one line after declaring oMsg Object which solved the problem. But still before the message window opens Outlook asks for the users permission to display the email.

***Yet I wouldn't mark this as the Answer because it's not the best solution you can give for this question.

UPDATE: I found out that the above mentioned issue was due to some security system in our server. This is the correct answer. Thanks to @MikeMiller for showing the correct path