# Office VSTO add-in possible permission issues - HRESULT 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

We've developed a C# Office VSTO add-in, that communicates with a running Outlook instance (or starts a new one), and it is showing signs of having permission issues on some customers PCs while trying to create Outlook tasks or appointments...

The exception message is the following:

> Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

This happens here:

```
Outlook.Account DefaultAccount = null;
Outlook.Application outlookApp = GetOutlookApp();    //returns Application object of running Outlook instance / creates a new instance - it works for them.

DefaultAccount = GetAccountForFolder(outlookApp);    //returns the default account of the user. Tried it with a simple setup, only one account etc. - it works for them
String defaultemailaddress;

//CODE RUNS UNTIL THIS POINT
if (DefaultAccount == null)    //if somehow this would end up NULL, which is not the case, because: see code snippet below!
{
    defaultemailaddress = outlookApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address;
}
else
{
    defaultemailaddress = DefaultAccount.SmtpAddress;    //this could be the problem, but I can't debug it further, and it works in the code block below, to get the AccountType, so I don't understand why I couldn't get the SmtpAddress without a hard exception
}
//FAILS BEFORE THIS LINE COULD RUN.
String email = "test@emailserver.com";
```

After getting in contact with the user, they told us, that they're running under a really limited permission set and network.

Weird thing is, this snippet of code actually runs smoothly for them, which proves, that the connection is working between Outlook and the other Office add-in:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = GetOutlookApp();
Outlook.Account DefaultAccount = GetAccountForFolder(oApp);
String AccountType = DefaultAccount.AccountType.ToString();
```

The IT department already tried to adjust the security policies of Outlook on the affected PC. They allowed Programmatic Access.

They can't start the tools with administrator privileges, but it shouldn't be necessary. The fact that those last 3 lines of code work (which gets the account type) proves that the application is indeed starting up correctly, but it looks like it can only run certain features...

I also want to note, that they are using Exchange, but apparently they don't have sync issues (if these could affect anything, at all...)

EDIT:
Here's the implementation of GetAccountForFolder, which gets the default Outlook.Account object. This is a code snippet that I've found laying around, and found it was working great.

```
public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForFolder(Outlook.Application outlookApp)
{
    // Obtain the store on which the folder resides.
    Outlook.Store store = outlookApp.Session.DefaultStore;

    // Enumerate the accounts defined for the session.
    foreach (Outlook.Account account in outlookApp.Session.Accounts)
    {
        // Match the DefaultStore.StoreID of the account
        // with the Store.StoreID for the currect folder.
        if (account.DeliveryStore.StoreID == store.StoreID)
        {
            // Return the account whose default delivery store
            // matches the store of the given folder.
            return account;
        }
    }
    // No account matches, so return null.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is your implementation of GetAccountForFolder? Do yo use the same problem in OutlookSpy? (click Namespace button, select Accounts, click Browse, go to the IEnumVariant tab, double click on the account in question).

Comment: Hi Dmitry! Thank you for your active work around anything Outlook related, I've found a lot of your comments/answers being helpful! Do you mean that I should ask the user to have OutlookSpy installed, and use it for this investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have [race condition in a COM Add-In object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/08/13/comaddins-race-condition/). You should make an artificial delay in your method. Simple make the retries until you succeed, like this:

```
bool isDone = false;
while (!isDone)
{
    try
    {
        // your action with Add-In here...

        isDone = true;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exception)
    {
        // small delay
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So I get error 0x80004004 because one of the objects are not accessible YET by my add-in. I think the important thing here, is that we're communicating with Outlook, from outside of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to allow for a slight delay after fetching the Account.

```
Outlook.Account DefaultAccount = null;
Outlook.Application outlookApp = GetOutlookApp();
DefaultAccount = GetAccountForFolder(outlookApp); 
Thread.Sleep(5000); // a bit of startup grace time.
```

The Aborted 0x80004004 error often shows up in Interop.Outlook due to this, see [Can only send email via Outlook if Outlook is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330101/can-only-send-email-via-outlook-if-outlook-is-open)